# JPA how to find top 500 in a answer table where the user table is a join and we are looking for answers where userid equals something

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

The question regards the JPA syntax as in findTop500... the rest I cant figure out. I have tried following with errors and looked through stack with no specific answers regarding autogenerated JPQL. A custom query is not sufficient for this task:

```
List<Answer> findTop500ByOrderByIdanswerDescWhereUserIduser(@Param("iduser")  long iduser);
```

&

```
List<Answer> findTop500ByIdanswerWhereUserIduserOrderByIdanswerDesc(@Param("iduser")  long iduser);
```

Answer table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="answer")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Idanswer")
    private long idanswer;


 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Useriduser", referencedColumnName = "Iduser")
    private User user;
}
```

User table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Iduser")
    private long iduser;

}
```

Comment: Why you don't want create it with `@Query`?

Comment: why is not an answer :D:P, its a question, its easy to do so, looking for a deeper understanding of the JPA syntax, thats why

Comment: Try this jpql: `select a from Answer a join User u where a.user = u.iduser and u.iduser = ? order by a.voteCount desc;`. To limit result set to 500 use `query.setMaxResults(500);` Here `a.voteCount` keeps number of upvotes.

Comment: kindly notice I am not looking for a custom JPQL, thank you

Comment: @Em.C ' looking for a deeper understanding of the JPA syntax' - set show_sql and check different variant that you have. or for real  deeper understanding try debug , and see how it works

Comment: "findByBlahBlahBlah" is NOT part of JPA API. It is SPRING!

Comment: thank you for your feedback, good to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create it like that:

```
List<Answer> findTop500ByUserIduserOrderByIdanswerDesc(long iduser);
```

You have to base on your entity mapping so -> BY user.iduser

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A small update though, the correct answer is   
   List<Answer>  
   findTop500ByUserIduserOrderByIdanswerDesc(@Param("iduser")  long 
   iduser); The reason is that we are looking for iduser in Answer table where Idanswer is the primary key and thereby new answer means higher idnumber. In order to get the latest 500 answers one must user OrderByIdanswer because the UserIduser is always the same(long iduser)